# How can I add my application in Google App

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

Can you help out me in detail that, how can i add/list my web application in Google App or Google Apps Marketplace for Google App users. Here my web application has own domain and want to make it free.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps

1. Login to http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/
2. Click on "Become a Vendor" on top right corner and create your company/vendor profile.(If already created click on "My Vendor Profile".
3. Now create your First listing.
4. If it is an installable app check on "My product may be directly installed into Google Apps domains".
5. Create an Application manifest as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/manifest). Manifest contains all the info about your product, product urls, google integrations that you have done, support links
6. Fill in the other details App Name,Overview, Pricing,...etc., and now your app is ready to Submit

More info available [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/)

Answer (score 0):

The band news is that you'll have to crank $100 before you can submit your first app - even if it's free.

I assume it's an "installable app".

1. Visit your vendor profile: http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewVendorProfile
2. Select your app from the list and click "Submit for approval".

Also keep in mind that often it's initially rejected. I've been asked to add some instructions, although the app was for developers, then to add a navigation link despite the app was all about one Gmail gadget and navlink was redundant (such requirement was added to Marketplace terms in the mean time). Finally I was asked to confirm that my app is not vulnerable to a certain OAuth security issue. All that back and forth took about two weeks.